# Html Helper for <ICollection>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model that has a  of items that are equipment for a session and I want to create a new session but I am not sure how to use a HTML helper to achieve this, here is the view model:

```
public class SessionInsertViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Equipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

}
```

and here is the Form on my view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Session.Insert(), FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form label-inline", name = "iform", enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "Insert" }))
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClassId)
                        <div class="formSep">
                            <label class="req">Session Name</label>
                            <div style="color:red;display:none" id="reqTitle">This Field is required to create a Session</div>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "medium", id="Title"})
                        </div>
                        <div class="formSep">
                            <span style="color:red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)</span>
                            <label class="req">Description</label>
                            <div style="color:red;display:none" id="reqDesc">This Field is required to create a Session</div>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description,new{style="width: 420px; height: 6em;"})
                        </div>
                        <div class="formSep">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="text-align:left"><span>Date</span></th>
                                    <th style="text-align:left"><div>Time</div></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="padding-right: 20px;"><input id="StartDate" type="text" style="width:120px" /></th>
                                    <th><input id="Hour" value="12:00" type="text" style="width:67px" /></th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>                     
                        <div class="formSep">
                           <label class="req">Duration (In Minutes)</label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Duration, new { @class = "medium", id = "Duration" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="formSep">
                            <label class="req">Difficulty</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Difficulty, new SelectList(new List<Object> { new { value = "Easy", text = "Easy" }, new { value = "Medium", text = "Medium" }, new { value = "Difficult", text = "Difficult" } }, "value", "text", @Model.Difficulty), new { id="Difficulty" })
                        </div>      





                        </div>      

                    }
```

So I need to be able to select a list of Equipment in the form and send it with the ViewModel to the controller but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the possible options for the dropdowns in the Model, not in the View.

Then you can pass them the other way (so from Controller > Model > View).

Sample:

Model:

```
public class SessionInsertViewModel
{
    // existing code

    public List<Difficulty> Difficulties { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Difficulty
                     , new SelectList( Model.Difficulties
                                     , "Text"
                                     , "Value"
                                     )
                     )
```